# Problems mixing AS2 and AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

For the life of me I can't figure out how to trace out the current label in my movie's main timeline.  This is in AS3.

I have a button on stage that spans the timeline of the movie.  It detects keypresses.
I want to trace the current frame label that the play head is on.

```
on(keypress "<left>") { 
 trace(this);
 trace(this.currentFrameLabel);
 trace(this.currentLabel);
 trace(currentFrameLabel);
 trace(currentLabel);
}
```

I get "_level0" for this...and undefined for the rest.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You seem to be mixing AS2 and AS3 up.

Comment: I guess I should say that I've inherited someone's movie and it is an AS3 movie.  You're right, the code is not AS3.  :)

Comment: The answer solves the OP's problem but is completely unrelated to the title question. Hence, I've proposed to change the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you publishing an AS1/2 or an AS3 movie? `on(keypress "left")` is AS1 (not even 2), and `currentFrameLabel` and `currentLabel` are AS3 properties of the [MovieClip](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/index.html) class. You'll need to use event listeners in AS3:

```
addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDownHandler);
```

And if you are publishing for AS2, `currentFrameLabel` and `currentLabel` will be undefined but AS1/2 has the `MovieClip._currentframe` property which is an integer.

AS2 and AS3 are compiled into different bytecode ([AS1/2 gets compiled to AVM1 and AS3 to AVM2](http://www.actionscriptversions.com/avm1/)), so you cannot have them in the same compiled swf file.

Comment: You are totally right.  They were publishing as AS2!  This is a quick and dirty job so I'm just using _currentframe.  No style points for this project.  :)  Thanks!